# Generating new form with javascript with onclick of button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to let my user to generate a form for adding team member as much as they need automatically by JavaScript and w3c dom. but it is not working.

Here is my JavaScript function and also the html page and the form I am trying to generate:

```js
var counter = 0;

function member_card()
{
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('teamform').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
  if (theName)
   newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('addform');
 insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}

window.onload = member_card;
```

```html
<section class="container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
        <div class="row addform">
            <div class="col-md-6 addform-col">

                <div class="row input-field">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="add-lable">Team Member<spna style="color:red">*</spna></label>
                    </div>

                        <div name="teamform" class="col-md-6" style="display: none">
                            <form>
                            <div name="imageholder" class="row tm-image-holder">
                                <div class="col-md-12"><div style="background-image: url(../img/DSC_3305.jpg);" class="tm-img"></div></div>
                            </div>
                            <a name="photo" href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary inout-margin mybut"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Browse Photo</a>
                            <input name="name" type="text" class="add-input input-margin" placeholder="Name, Mohammad, ... *">
                            <input name="job" type="text" class="add-input" placeholder="Job, Developer, Designer, ... *">
                            <textarea name="explain" class="add-textarea input-margin" rows="4" placeholder="Explain this member in 2 to 4 lines *"></textarea>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    <form method="post" action="">
                        <input type="button" id="member_card" value="Give me more fields!" />
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no element with id = "teamform". You need to change 
      `name="teamform"` to `id="teamform"`
in your html.

To see this kind of problem, it's usually easiest to try running your code in Chrome or some other browser that has a Developer Tools, and opening up the debugger console to see how your code is failing.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var counter = 0;

function member_card()
{
    counter++;
    debugger;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('teamform').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
  if (theName)
   newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('addform');
 insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}

window.onload = member_card;
```

```html
<section class="container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
        <div class="row addform" id="addform">
            <div class="col-md-6 addform-col">

                <div class="row input-field">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="add-lable">Team Member<spna style="color:red">*</spna></label>
                    </div>

                        <div id="teamform" class="col-md-6" style="display: none">
                            <form>
                            <div name="imageholder" class="row tm-image-holder">
                                <div class="col-md-12"><div style="background-image: url(../img/DSC_3305.jpg);" class="tm-img"></div></div>
                            </div>
                            <a name="photo" href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary inout-margin mybut"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Browse Photo</a>
                            <input name="name" type="text" class="add-input input-margin" placeholder="Name, Mohammad, ... *">
                            <input name="job" type="text" class="add-input" placeholder="Job, Developer, Designer, ... *">
                            <textarea name="explain" class="add-textarea input-margin" rows="4" placeholder="Explain this member in 2 to 4 lines *"></textarea>
                            </form>
                        </div>


                    

                    <form method="post" action="">
                        <input type="button" id="member_card" value="Give me more fields!" />
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```